# ACF - force fields initialize when post is created

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a post created upon user creation which is associated to that ID.

There are a long series of acf fields connected to that post: only one major issue.
Those fields are not “initialized” by default but only if someone updates the specific post via backend.

Is there any solution to reproduce a “full” or a “real” post update like the one in the backend?
I tried with a sort of initialization with a $wpdb update of any meta_key but no luck, and even with a post update from the front end from which any author can update their own post...

I am stuck as ACF support redirected me here as my problem was out of their scope...

Tyvm

Comment: In short, you want to operate ACF from frontend but using native functions?

Comment: I do not have any specific preferences: the fact is, when I create the post, ACF fields should be "ready" to be used, like it happens when an admin "updates" the post via backend.

I thinking about using some sort of initialization after wp_insert_post using wp_update_post but have no clue if I must pass ALL the meta_key=ACF_field_name or something else...

Comment: There were two plugins which tried to use ACF in the same way as you are trying. One of them was "loushou-acf-for-woocommerce" and another was "POI ACF for WP". It can help for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a proper way by using acf_form and acf_form_header, which basically reproduce the same functionalities of the backend.